# Caching read-mostly values: are time lookups cheaper than atomic operations?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, cpu

My multithreaded app uses a bunch of read-mostly values. These values are configuration values, and only change when the operator edits the config file and instructs the app to reload the config file without downtime. The values are accessed from multiple threads. None of the threads mutate the value. Mutation only occurs when the config file is reloaded.

Because the values *can* change, accessing them requires some form of synchronization. But because they change so rarely, I do not want to use mutexes:

- A normal mutex disallows multiple threads from accessing the values concurrently. Since the threads only read the values, concurrent access by the threads are safe as long as the config file isn't being reloaded.
- A read-write mutex sounds like a good solution, but they have high constant overhead.

I could go lower level and use atomic operations directly. For example, I can make the Config object immutable, with an atomic pointer to the latest version:

- Upon reloading the config file, I create a new Config object and atomically update the pointer to the currently-active Config object.
- The reader threads would then just atomically load the pointer and use the Config object without synchronization, since it is immutable.

However, atomic operations themselves are not free either. I have a hard time finding information on what sort of overhead they exactly impose (CPU pipeline stalls? Some sort communication overhead between CPU cores? Do they limit concurrency? Not sure.) but I get the feeling that it's better to avoid them when possible.

So I got the idea of caching the config pointer for a limited amount of time, e.g. for 1 second. The cached pointer is accessed without synchronization. But this assumes that time lookups are less expensive and have less impact on concurrency than atomic pointer operations. Is this true?

**So my main question is:**

- Are time lookups cheaper than atomic pointer operations?

  - Does the overhead depend on the granularity? For example, are seconds-granularity time lookups cheaper than nanosecond-granularity?
  - I am mostly interested in Linux, but information about other platforms are welcome too.

My **secondary questions** (for better understanding the problem) are:

- What exactly is the overhead of a time lookup on various operating systems? What happens during a time lookup? Does the kernel need to be called (a system call)?
- What exactly is the overhead of an atomic pointer load and store? What exactly happens in the CPU?

Additional information about my environment and use case:

- I am using Go for this app, but I am interested in general, language-independent information. I also have another C++ app that is heavily concurrent, so I would appreciate answers that are as language-independent as possible.
- My primary production platform is x86_64 Linux, so I am mostly interested in information about that platform. But since my app is used by a diverse range of users, I have to be at least aware of the caveats for other platforms, even if I don't particularly optimize for them.

Comment: What are "time lookups"? If you update a value from a timer then both readers and writers must synchronize.

Comment: C's `time()`, `gettimeofday()`, or Go's `time.Now()`. That kind of stuff.

Comment: A key question here is - do you require strict ordering? i.e - could a thread observe an older config at a later time than another thread observing the newer one

Comment: I do not require strict ordering. It is fine if a thread still observes the older config for some time, as long as they all *eventually* observe the new config. Within reason of course: it shouldn't take a day before they all observe the new config, but something like 5 seconds is fine.

Comment: Your problem seems like a perfect fit for `RCU`. Note that even with atomic accesses with relaxed memory ordering (free or cheap on general-purpose multiprocessor systems), you need to synchronize to ensure the old value is no longer in use when you delete it. This is where `RCU` comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a partial answer:

All low level languages have a way to cheaply and atomically load a value from memory. This does not require an interlocked access on x86. In fact, on x86 it is just a regular load instruction. All we need to do is to prevent the compiler and runtime (if any) from reordering this memory access. It's a compiler barrier.

In C# this facility is surfaced through the `Volatile` class. In C++ there is now `atomic`. I'm not sure what consistency level is required. It's probably an acquire load (which is cheap on x86). MSVC also applies these semantics to `volatile` variables. I do not know about other compilers. The C standard certainly does *not* specify these semantics for volatile but some compilers do.

This facility is so cheap that I think you can stop looking for anything else. This operation should hit a shared CPU cache line almost always (except right after a store has been made).

See Herb Sutters video series "Atomic Weapons" for more details. Frankly, he's also a more reliable source than I am.

Comment: Thanks. How are interlocked access different from atomic operations? From what I understand, interlocked instructions used to lock the memory bus, preventing other CPUs from accessing the memory address, but I've also heard that things no longer work like that on modern CPU architectures? Do concurrent atomic loads *not* lock things on the CPU level? And am I correct in understanding that with "interlocked access", you mean the x86 assembly "lock" instruction, and not the `Interlocked*()` family of API calls in Windows?

Comment: `atomic` has multiple access modes which generate different code. Generally, pick the lightest level that is enough (and that you are confident about that it works). For loads and stores I think any access generates just a normal x86 instruction. Interlocked operations are generated for when you need to atomically do multiple things such as incrementing. This does not apply here. On ARM, there are some memory barriers required.

Comment: `lock` prefix and `Interlocked` are often the same thing, except, I believe, for simple loads and stores. (Again, only on x86).